# Unable to add products to cart

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Store 2.4 and EE 2.9. I've got a simple product with dynamic pricing to allow the user to set the price of this particular item.

```
{exp:store:product_form return="vanpool/store/checkout"}
  {exp:store:product entry_id="19339" disable_form="yes"} 
  <input type="hidden" name="item_qty" value="1" />

      <label class="field_label" for="price">Amount to Pay *</label>
      <input id="price" class="large" name="price" type="text" value="" />

      <label class="field_label" for="notes">Notes </label>
      <textarea name="order_custom1"></textarea>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay Now" />
  </p>

    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:store:product_form}
```

I've tried everything I could find here with regards to htaccess, trying different servers, etc. The form posts but the cart is never updated with the item. I've tried being logged in and logged out. I do see the orders being generated for the cart in the control panel but they're missing info: http://cl.ly/image/1g1E0R0y2T2L

I'm completely stuck on this. Any ideas?

Comment: So, This seems to be a misunderstanding on my part of how to create a product with no price (a la donations). I've tried it with a regular product (with a price) and it works fine...

Comment: I removed the product_form tag and now I can successfully add this product to the cart but it always has a $0 total instead of the amount entered into the price field. It's just not applying that field for some reason.

Comment: Not sure what fixed it for me but it's working now..

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I could think of, this is working as expected now. I'm sure I must have missed something simple along the way.